# PHP Returning a string from a function to be used later on?

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

```
function foo() {
    $foo1= mysql_query();
    $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($foo1);
    $word= $db_field['word'];
    $lower=strtolower($word);
}
foo();
print $lower;
```

The function above executes a block of code with the endgame being the `$lower` variable, which is the lowercase of a word from a database. As the code is written above, I get an error saying that `$lower is not defined`.

I tried returning `$lower` with `return $lower`, but that didn't work. How do I keep a variable from a function for later use?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `return $lower` at the end of the function is correct. Then you use:

```
$var = foo();
```

You just discoverd the scope of a variable. `$lower` is only availible inside the function, so you cant use it outside of it.

Comment: +1 for "You just discoverd the scope of a variable."

Answer (score 0):

`$lower` is defined inside the function which have scope only within that function. So trying to access it outside the function will definitely cause proble. You have to return it in the function .Try with :

```
function foo() {
    $foo1= mysql_query();
    $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($foo1);
    $word= $db_field['word'];
    return strtolower($word);  // return the value
}
$lower=foo();   // this will contain the return value of foo()
print $lower;
```

Comment: No idea why you assign it to a variable and then return it, you could just use `return strtolower($word);`

Answer (score 0):

put your return statement back

```
...
return $lower;
}

$result = foo();
print $result;
```

Comment: Without return value from function, we cant get it.

Comment: he had the return in his description so I thought he was mostly there. I'll edit my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

`$lower` variable used only in the function. it can't work out of the function. Do like this,

```
function foo() {
    $foo1= mysql_query();
    $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($foo1);
    $word= $db_field['word'];
    $lower=strtolower($word);
  return $lower;
}

$lower = foo();
print $lower;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use 'global'
Like This.

```
    $lower = '';

    function foo() {

        global $lower;

        $foo1= mysql_query();
        $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($foo1);
        $word= $db_field['word'];
        $lower=strtolower($word);

    }

    foo();
    print $lower;
```